# How to get specific start & end time in ffmpeg by Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to cut a video in specific start & end time & save it. I cant understand how to cut specific time of that video by Node JS.

Video copy code :

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve ,reject){
        var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
        ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname,'..','..','/video.mp4')))
            .seekInput('01:00')
            .duration('02:00')
            .outputOptions('-strict experimental')
            .on('start', function(commandLine) {
                console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
                }).on('end', function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('conversion Done');
                    //res.send("conversion Done");
                    resolve();
                }
                }).on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log('error: ', +err);
                    reject(err);
                }).save(path.join(__dirname,'..','..','/test.mp4'));
    });
```

Comment: I am getting on console NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check following steps and sample code,

1. Install  [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed on your system [steps](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/wiki)
2. Install module [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) in your project
3. Please check following sample code

   ```
     function clipVideo() {

         var params = {
           input: 'input_file',
           start: 0,
           duration: 10,
           output: 'output_file'
         };

         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

             ffmpeg(params.input)
                 .setStartTime(params.start)
                 .setDuration(params.duration)
                 .save(params.output)
                 .on('start', function(commandLine) {
                     console.log('start : ' + commandLine);
                 })
                 .on('progress', function(progress) {
                     console.log('In Progress !!' + Date());
                 })
                 .on('end', function() {
                     console.log("downlaod resolved");
                     return resolve(params.clippedFile);

                 })
                 .on('error', function(err) {
                     console.log("reject");
                     return reject(err);
                 })
         });
     }
   ```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: I am getting an error after executing above code 
```an error happened: ffmpeg exited with code 1: home/santosh/video1.avi: Invalid data found when processing input```

Comment: you needs to passed full path of input video and output path , for example Users/santosh/Documents/Workspace/VideoClip/routes/input.mp4

Comment: Yes. It was path issue
Thank you .